# Ошибка при скачивании lightfm python

Tags: python, pip

Я хотел установить LightFm: `pip install lightfm nmslib`

И тут эта ошибка

```
Collecting lightfm
  Using cached lightfm-1.15.tar.gz (302 kB)
Collecting nmslib
  Using cached nmslib-2.0.6.tar.gz (182 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\пк\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nwzblik4\\nmslib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ПК\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nwzblik4\\nmslib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-g3oh3gzs'
         cwd: C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nwzblik4\nmslib\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ПК\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nwzblik4\nmslib\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Windows 32-bit is not supported.")
    RuntimeError: Windows 32-bit is not supported.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Что делать?

Comment: Поставить Windows 64-bit, очевидно же! (Хотя на самом деле начните с 64-битного Питона)

Comment: Написано ведь в трассе: `Windows 32-bit is not supported.` :) Придется и питон поставить соответствующей версии